# How do I compute the inverse of transfer function matrix?

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory, block-matrices, linear-control

For reference, I am linking the Zhou textbook [pdf](https://www.lirmm.fr/%7Echemori/Temp/Control_books/robust_and_optimal_control-zhou.pdf) available online.
I want to understand an equation appearing in Lemma 5.3 (on page 122 of the book).

In its proposition, it has the following identity:

For transfer functions $P(s) = P$ and $K(s) = K$,

$$\begin{bmatrix}I & -K \\ -P & I\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}I + K(I-PK)^{-1}P & K(I-PK)^{-1} \\ (I-PK)^{-1}P & (I-PK)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$

It does not seem to be derived from standard matrix inverse as it deals with transfer functions. How do I compute the inverse of transfer function matrix such as the one above? Is there a general formula for such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [block matrix inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) states that if a square matrix $X$ can be partitioned into four blocks $$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\
    \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}
  \end{bmatrix},$$ then provided that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$ are both invertible, the inverse of $\mathbf{X}$ is given by
$$\mathbf{X}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\
    \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
     \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
      -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1} \\
    -\left(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
       \left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

The specific formula you stated is a special case where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ are both identity matrices.